# Greasemonkey script to replace a static segment in changeable URLs of the same website

Tags: greasemonkey

Many different pages on a single (fictional) website https://www.brightideas.org contain segment '=eng' and I want to replace it, for example, with '=rus' to access its page in the corresponding language.
Example of URL: https://www.brightideas.org/gardening-skills/25/how-to-grow-a-tree?lang=**eng**
Segment '=eng' is always located at the end of the URLs.

Can anyone help me with a script that will accomplish this task?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is:

```
var oldHref = window.location.href;
if(str.endsWith("eng")){
    var newHref = oldHref .replace("eng", "rus");
}else{
    console.log("Error in Script")
}
```

greets

Alex